# How to select given value matching property value in JSON?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to select a given value matching property value in JSON. It means I pass `configuration_code` and I want to select `description` value.

```
configurations: Array(2)
  0:
  configuration_code: "SPWG"
  description: "Cuscade Cus Date"
  1:
  configuration_code: "KKS"
  description: "Krop Kret Sowel"
  ...
```

Tried code:

```
configDelete: function(index, config) {
  console.log(this.quote.configurations.find(x => x.configuration_code[config] == index).description);
}
```

If I pass the `SPWG` this should console `Cuscade Cus Date` and If I pass the `KKS` this should console `Krop Kret Sowel`.

But my tried code not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm confused: how is this javascript?
If a library is involved, please add to tags.

Comment: @iAmOren Actually this is VueJs function. Inside that function I used JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below snippet could help you

```js
const configurations = [
  {
    configuration_code: 'CCD',
    description: 'Cuscade Cus Date'
  },
  {
    configuration_code: 'KKS',
    description: 'Krop Kret Sowel'
  }
]

const getDescription = (configurations, code) =>
  configurations.find(
    configuration => configuration.configuration_code === code
  ).description

console.log(getDescription(configurations, 'CCD'))
console.log(getDescription(configurations, 'KKS'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var printDescription = (configurations, code) => {
    let config = configurations.find(c => c. configuration_code === code);
    console.log(config.description);
}
```

See code snippet below:

```js
const configurations = [{
        configuration_code: 'CCD',
        description: 'Cuscade Cus Date'
    },
    {
        configuration_code: 'KKS',
        description: 'Krop Kret Sowel'
    }
];

var printDescription = (configurations, code) => {
    let config = configurations.find(c => c. configuration_code === code);
    console.log(config.description);
}

printDescription(configurations, 'CCD');
printDescription(configurations, 'KKS');
```